# How can I sort the day in sql?

Tags: sql, mysqli

How can I sort this value in sql "M-W-F, Sat, T-Th" wherein the output is in the table and will look like this:

- M-W-F
- T-Th
- Sat

Comment: Add `ID` column beside where it says `1, 2, 3` and sort it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a case expression for this:

```
ORDER BY CASE
            WHEN Col = `M-W-F` THEN 1
            WHEN col = `T-Th` THEN 2
            WHEN col = `Sat` THEN 3
            ELSE 4
         END
```